# Make multiple threads exec a single command

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm actually working on a little script that creates dummy files, used to fill a disk (usb key in general), for security purpose.

Actually, I use the threading module, and even if I kind of know how to use it, I'm still struggling with something.

Here's a bit of code that introduce my problem.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3: # Check Python's version, and dismiss Python 3
    raise Exception('You must use Python 2 to launch this program')

from threading import Thread

index, running = 0, True

def main():
    multiThreading()

def multiThreading():
    thread1 = Thread(target=fill) # Both threads targets fill()
    thread1.daemon = True
    thread1.start()

    thread2 = Thread(target=fill)
    thread2.daemon = True
    thread2.start()

    while running: # Without this infinite loop, the program exits while the threads are still on, which is not really a problem in this bit of code, 
    # as they finish their tasks, but it is one in the original script. Anyway.
        if running is False:
            return None

def fill(): # this function  normally fills a chosen drive with data
    global index
    global running
    while running:
        index += 1
        print index
        if index >= 10:
            running = False
            # The index is used AFTER index += 1 is executed, which causes a problem


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

print 'End'
```

Which returns

```
12

34

56

78

910

End
>>>
```

The thing is that actually, I want it to print

```
1

2

3

...

10

End
>>>
```

But both thread pass by the index, which adds 2 instead of 1 (2 because there is two thread of course)

I tried with watch dogs, with other functions, but the result is the same.
And also, a one-time watch dog isn't the solution, as I want to make a loop as many times as needed.

Predicted question: Why use multi-threads ? Because it makes the file creation much faster.

Do you have a solution ? Thanks a lot for reading !

PS: Please forgive my few English mistakes, not being my mother tongue :p ; double-PS: if you got a better idea for the title, my ears are all open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because when several threads write to a stream (stdout or file), their output will almost certainly mix and produce unreadable results. You get at least partially ordered output mostly because python has GIL. (Btw, I get different output.) In general case, when language is not specified, nothing stops OS from scheduling thread execution in a, for example, following way:

```
index += 1  # Thread 1
index += 1  # Thread 2
print index # Thread 2
index += 1  # Thread 2 (next iteration)
print index # Thread 1
```

So in general, when you write* to shared variables, you need to guard that part of code with a mutex, semaphore or other synchronization primitive to make sure a thread can execute the whole *critical section* without being interrupted:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

index_operations_lock = Lock()

def mutlithreading():
    # all the stuff you already have
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()

def fill():
    global index
    global running
    while running:
        with index_operations_lock:
            if index >= 10:
                running = False
                return
            index += 1
            print index
```

Guard your contested resources. Also, please note, this approach does not specify order of thread execution. If you need to write from thread one and then from thread two, you'll need whether two more locks or to implement producer-consumer pattern (i. e. make two threads write in queues, have third thread read from queues and write to a file / stdout).

---

* - In python, assignment `a = b` is a write too, because this increments reference counter in the object that is referenced by `b`.